# Typeclass constraints necessary for a function that prints integers not greater than 10 in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to program in Haskell a function that takes an integer and prints it only if it is less than or equal to 10.

In ghci, executing a function programmed like this:

`sayMeUntilTen :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> String
sayMeUntilTen x = if x <= 10 then  show x else "Sorry, greater than 10"`

works.

However if I don't include the constraint `Show a` ghci displays the following error:

> • Could not deduce (Show a) arising from a use of ‘show’
>        from the context:
>
> Integral a
>          bound by the type signature for:
>                     sayMeUntilTen :: forall a. Integral a => a -> String
>
> Possible fix:
>          add (Show a) to the context of
>            the type signature for:
>              sayMeUntilTen :: forall a. Integral a => a -> String

I don't understand why adding `Show a` is necessary. Isn't `Integral` like a "subset" of `Show`? Looking for information I found this website: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types

It describes the inheritance relations between typeclases in Haskell with this picture:

[image]

It leads me to think that the `Show` type class constraint is already implied by the `Integral` one but there is obviously something I'm misunderstanding.

**Could anyone explain to me why is `Show` necessary ?**

Sorry if the question is too stupid, I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: That diagram used to be correct, but since then they removed some arrows from that (and added others, e.g. functor => applicative => monad).

Comment: Eurgh. That is awful, what is such an outdated hierarchy diagram doing on Wikibooks? Anybody active there? I [made an updated version of the diagram](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/haskell-report/blob/b30d2690e4dfc5cda8022eea488ce60944b8139c/report/classes.pdf), just in case...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The diagram is simply quite out of date. On GHC 8.0.2 (and any after 7.4?)

```
Prelude> :i Num
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
  {-# MINIMAL (+), (*), abs, signum, fromInteger, (negate | (-)) #-}
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
```

`Integral` does not impose `Show` therefore the `Show` constraint has to be given explicitly due to your `show` usage.